# Expose specific parts of the Backlog and let users report bugs in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, agile, azure-boards

We are working with Azure DevOps to organize our development process. Recently we started to additionally develop a fork of our standard product directly for a customer.

Is it possible to let them view a specific part of our backlog and let them report bugs directly to us with our on-boarding them completely into our project?

The customers project managers are non-technical users that feel kind of overwhelmed from ado. I already experimented with Boards but didn't get the result we need.

Answer (score 2):

If each client has a specific Work Item Area it can be configured in such a way that users can be configured in such a way that they can only edit and see work items in that area.

Be careful, in the user drop-down these users can still see all users, that will include the users from others clients. And they will be able to see other work item areas, including the names of other clients in that case.

To separate out the clients a bit, they need to be in separate projects.

To separate clients fully they need their own Azure DevOps organization.

See:

- [Set Permission Access for Work Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking)